# Is there an R function to apply rasterstack to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply, r-raster

I´m totally new T R(studio) and try to build raster stacks. My input are around 600jp2 files and they are all in the same directory looking like this Image of the files in the directory (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcvpn.png)

The files are sorted so that band number 2,3,4 and 8 are alwas in a row of 4. According to that my raster stack should contain always these 4 bands.
I want to make a loop/function whatever so that R takes 4 files then do the rasterstack and then take the next 4 files and do the raster stack again and so on.

So my attempt was to store all the files in a data frame an split it, so that in each dataframe I have exactly the 4 bands I need. So that worked and I created a list which contains all the dataframes (and each with 4 bands). Afterwards i wanted to use lapply to assign raster::stack and here comes the problem.
I have to assign every daataframe with$ to do the raster:stack. As long as i do so the result is fine but I would have to write the same "code" all the time just changing the value behind the$.
I thought when using lapply all the dataframes in one list will be assigned. How can I call all the data frames at once (I tried using []) and assign the function raster::stack? I will add some images so hopefully one understands my problem
[Using lapply, calling each data frame with $, d calling all data frames at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS2JN.png)

[That should be the result for all the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnC3v.png)

[Thats the result if i try to call all dfs at once with [], it just adds the ind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or7ms.png)

Answer (score 1):

When asking an R question, you should always include some example data and code. And always include the output as text, never as images (unless the output is a plot, of course).

Example filenames

```
ff <- paste0("202001", rep(c("01", "06", "11"), each=4), "_B0", c(2:4,8), ".png")
ff
#[1] "20200101_B02.png" "20200101_B03.png" "20200101_B04.png" "20200101_B08.png"
#[5] "20200106_B02.png" "20200106_B03.png" "20200106_B04.png" "20200106_B08.png"
#[9] "20200111_B02.png" "20200111_B03.png" "20200111_B04.png" "20200111_B08.png"
```

Remove the files you do not want and split by date

```
sf <- ff[-grep("B08", ff)]
date <- substr(basename(sf), 1, 8)
s <- split(sf, date)
str(s)
#List of 3
# $ 20200101: chr [1:3] "20200101_B02.png" "20200101_B03.png" "20200101_B04.png"
# $ 20200106: chr [1:3] "20200106_B02.png" "20200106_B03.png" "20200106_B04.png"
# $ 20200111: chr [1:3] "20200111_B02.png" "20200111_B03.png" "20200111_B04.png"
```

The "terra" package has replaced the "raster" package, so let's use that and make a list of SpatRasters.

```
library(terra)
x <- lapply(s, rast)
```

But you could do the equivalent with the raster package and `stack`.

```
library(raster)
x <- lapply(s, stack)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped me a lot and I get the output I want. Luckily you understood me eventhough I asked it in a bad way (sry for that). I´m a total newbie, althoug in asking questions. Will definetly change that and consider your input. Thanks again!